# Mapbox Error: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am building a web map using `mapbox gl js` and every thing was working but now from nowhere I get this error:

> Error {message: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"}

[image]

While it was working before a day and nothing changed in the code:

[image]

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/data';

map.addSource('features', {
  type: 'geojson',
  data: url
});

map.addLayer({
  'id': 'features-layer',
  'type': 'circle',
  'source': 'features',
  'paint': {
    'circle-color': '#ccc',
    'circle-radius': 10,
    'circle-opacity': 0.6,
    'circle-stroke-width': 0.6,
    'circle-stroke-color': 'black',
  }
});
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the word "coordinates" in your geometry object is not correctly spelled, check the first screenshot line 24

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your code is demanding `someObject.0` but in your case that `someObject` is undefined which is why it is not able to locate property 0 that you want somewhere in your project.
It's really not a big issue, could have happened because you are using something asynchronous.

Debug your code with debugger keyword and you will definitely find something.
Since you didn't provide any code, the least I can say is provide a console to check values and locate where exactly you are getting undefined instead of being able to get the value from property.

Answer (score 0):

the fix for me was making sure the key was valid and it was reading it..

make sure you are using a public key (.pk) and not (.sk)!